# Encode Byte array to JPEG image in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, uiimage, arrays, jpeg

I have a file of raw data , its a image data. Now i need to convert the Raw data to JPEG image in Objective-C. 
STEPS:

1) Read the file containing the raw data into NSString.
2) Encode the string to JPEG encoder
3) Create an JPEG image

Can you please guide me how to achieve this?

Is there any library available in iPhone OS  to encode into JPEG.

Answer (score 4):

This is how you create a `UIImage` from JPEG data:

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:…]];
```

And this is how you create a JPEG representation of a `UIImage`:

```
NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(anImage, compressionQuality);
```

…but only after writing this I realized you probably want to create a JPEG image from raw image sample data? In that case you’ll probably have to create a `CGImage` with the correct image sample format and supply the bitmap data using a provider, see `CGImageCreate`. (Hopefully somebody can correct me or come up with sample code.) Then you can easily create an `UIImage` from the `CGImage` and use the code above.

Comment: thank you so much for the reply. I'm looking into CGImageCreate.